# What is the concept of truth in the Curry-Howard isomorphism?

Tags: logic, computer-science, proof-theory

Does the Curry-Howard isomorphism give a meaning or a new interpretation to the concept of classical boolean truth ?

The correspondence is about proofs and provability. Proofs are interpreted as programs and formulas/propositions as types. We can't say that a type is *true* or *false* but that we can *construct* a program according to a given type.

When considering only the intuitionistic world of Logic, "constructibility" or "realizability" doesn't seem to match with "truth". But quite recently, we discovered a Curry-Howard correspondence for Classical Logic through control operators and environements ($\lambda\mu$-calculus for instance).

What is truth ? Is it an information about the possibility of realizing a program with a given type ?

Comment: CH for classical logic has been known for a long time -- say, intuitionistic logic becomes classical if you add Peirce's law, which is a natural type to give to a call-with-current-continuation operator.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~lengrand/Work/Teaching/MPRI/Notes.pdf